# Objective-C - Adding items from NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm having trouble trying to load objects from an `NSDictionary` to an `NSMutableDictionary` - code is as follows :

```
dictListData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
```

...

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonResultDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[httpRequestCopy responseData] options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
NSDictionary *tempDataset = [[jsonResultDict objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSLog(@"tempDataset = %@", tempDataset);

[dictListData addEntriesFromDictionary:tempDataset];   // <-- Error here
```

The `NSLog` command outputs the data in a dictionary style format so I know the data is there, but the addEntriesFromDictionary command fails with the error :

`'NSInvalidArgumentException' [NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:]: dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary'.`

I've tried typecasting the tempDataset but made no difference.  Any ideas?

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2, targeting iOS SDK 5.1, ARC enabled.

```
jsonResultDict = {
    result =     (
                (
                        {
                stCode = 000477065;
                stDesc1 = "TIMER KNOB";
                stQtyFree = 0;
                stQtyInStock = 0;
            },
                        {
                stCode = 0010311;
                stDesc1 = "DBLE TAPER CHUCK CAP";
                stQtyFree = 10;
                stQtyInStock = 10;
            },
                        {
                stCode = "0016-103";
                stDesc1 = "1/8 I.D";
                stQtyFree = 0;
                stQtyInStock = 0;
            },
                        {
                stCode = "0016-104";
                stDesc1 = "1/4 I.D";
                stQtyFree = 0;
                stQtyInStock = 0;
            },
                        {
                stCode = "0016-157";
                stDesc1 = "1/8 x 1/16 X 1/8 TEE";
                stQtyFree = 0;
                stQtyInStock = 0;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: please post the json data or nslog the jsonResultDict

Comment: You could see what kind of class tempDataset is: NSLog(@"%@", [tempDataset className]); or set a breakpoint and see what it is in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the NSLog output for jsonResultDict.  Also the class name of tempDataset appears to be __NSCFArray ??

Comment: The result part of you json is not an object, but an array. So it will be deserialized to an NSArray. So either you have to change the data or change the target containers to be NS(Mutable)Array's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `tempDataset` is an `NSArray` class.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments, I think I can work with NSMutableArray, in fact this probably serves me better.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flink's answer that it is an NSArray class should be correct.  Also, if you really do need to convert an `NSDictionary` to an `NSMutableDictionary`, its far easier to use `myDictionary.mutableCopy`.